# Including Git tags in Visual Studio application

Tags: git, batch-file, msbuild, git-describe

I'm looking for a simple way to include the output of `git describe --t --dirty` in the title bar of a WPF program.

I've looked at MSBuild.Community.Tasks but I don't understand the build process too well. I haven't been able to find much recent information or any tutorial that put all the pieces together for me.

I tried writing a batch file to add a property to AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
@echo off
echo "Append Git Version Property"

for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`git describe --tags --dirty`) DO (
set var=%%F
)
echo Version: %var%
set statement=[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion(" %var% ")]
echo Property: %statement%
echo %statement% >> AssemblyInfo.cs
```

This seems to work if I run it from explorer. Adding this to my project file should run it after the build completes, I think.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>cmd  (SolutionDir)\Properties\gitVersion.bat</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It doesn't seem to change the file at all, when I do a build. I need to get it to actually add the property.

I don't know if the build creates a new file with each build. If not what I have will append a new property to the end of the file each time. That will not be good.

Update-- Whatever other issues there might be there must at least be something wrong with the way I am running it from the project file. I changed the output to a file I created, and changing it to a prebuild event. The bat file just doesn't seem to run. There are no errors.

Update 2:
I'm not sure if I should continue this or start a new question. Let me know if I am breaking etiquette.

per mister Dodd's comment I added a target to the project.

```
  <Target Name="GitVersionAttribute" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="git describe --tags --dirty &gt; $(IntermediateOutputPath)version.txt" />
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(IntermediateOutputPath)version.txt">
      <Output TaskParameter="Lines" PropertyName="VersionAttribute" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <WriteCodeFragment AssemblyAttributes="GitVersionAttribute" Language="C#" OutputDirectory="Properties" OutputFile="GitVersionAttribute.cs" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="Properties\GitVersionAttribute.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

I added a RunCommand to to bring in the return value from git describe. I still can't figure out how to set the value for GitVersionAttribute.

Comment: I've no idea what `AssemblyInfo.cs` does, but your code should *append* `%statement%` to the file. Consequently, from the information offered,  `AssemblyInfo.cs` should acquire an ever-increasing list of `[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion(" %var% ")]`. Would this affect your problem?

Comment: That file contains build parameters. I was hoping the build process deletes it and makes a new one. If not you are right. This will append an endless list of '[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion(" %var% ")]' lines. I just don't know how I would parse a file and replace just the '%var% part that changes in a batch file.

Comment: Is this an 'Sdk style' project or a 'Legacy'? Sdk projects support properties for the assembly info items including the AssemblyInformationalVersion.

Comment: The `AssemblyInfo.cs` file is part of the project template when Visual Studio generates a C# .Net Framework project. This will be a 'Legacy' type project. There is nothing special about the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file or name.

Comment: So, if this is a Legacy project, does that mean there is no support for AssemblyInformationalVersion? Is there someplace else I should be storing an alternate version numbering scheme?

Comment: No. It is just that you will need to do more work. :)

Comment: Have you tried loading the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in a editor to see whether it is accumulating these lines?

Comment: @Magoo the file is probably not committed and the change is thrown way.

Comment: So - having appended the line in batch, copy the resultant file to a temporary file which you can examine - like `"%temp%\savefile%random%.txt"`

Comment: The reason it appears to not work is because it needs to be on the `PreBuildEvent`. Running the batch file on `PostBuild` is changing the source after compilation has already been done. (But Shelling out creates some other issues.)

Answer (score 0):

The batch file is run in the `PostBuildEvent` which is after the build. i.e. it doesn't appear to do anything because it runs late in the process and, most importantly, after compilation.

From discussion in the comments it would appear that the project is a 'Legacy' style project targeting .Net Framework.

C# project files (.csproj) are MSBuild XML files. The top level document root element in an msbuild file is `Project`. An 'Sdk' style project will have an 'Sdk' attribute on the `Project` element. A 'Legacy' project will not.

'Sdk' projects support a set of properties for specifying many of the common assembly attributes. Since properties can be set via environment variables and the command line, it is very easy for a build system to inject the appropriate values.

'Legacy' projects don't have the properties. (But we are not stuck.)

The code

```cs
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("myversionstring")]
```

is the syntax for an [Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/). `assembly:` is specifying the [target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#attribute-targets) of the attribute.

This line of code can appear in any source file. There is nothing special about the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file or name.

A given assembly attribute can only be specified once for an assembly. Repeating the same assembly attribute anywhere in the source is an error.

e.g. The following code is a compile time error. Putting these two lines in separate files in the same project is still an error.

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("foo")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("bar")]
```

The `AssemblyInfo.cs` from the project template doesn't include `AssemblyInformationalVersion` so there shouldn't be a duplication issue. But it is something to be aware of, if you decide to dynamically update other attributes that do appear in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

With Visual Studio 2015 a task was added to MSBuild named [`WriteCodeFragment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/writecodefragment-task?view=vs-2022). Despite the name this task is not (presently) capable of writing any generic code fragment. But that's okay because the one and only type of code fragment it is capable of writing is assembly attribute code fragments. This task was added to support 'Sdk' style projects and, thankfully, it was added to MSBuild itself as a general use task.

To dynamically inject an `AssemblyInformationalVersion`:

1. Pass the value into the msbuild process
2. Create a target that is set to be executed `BeforeCompile`
3. In the target

   1. Use `WriteCodeFragment` to create a new file that defines the attribute
   2. `Include` the new file in the `Compile` items

**Update with Example Code**

Example code to add an AssemblyInformationalVersion:

```xml
<!-- Directory.Build.targets -->
<Project>
  <!--<Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('$(MSBuildThisFile)', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../'))" />-->

  <Target Name="AddAssemblyInformationalVersion" BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile">
    <!-- The 'InfoVersionFile' property shoud be set with the value to use for the AssemblyInformationalVersion. -->

    <!-- Path and name of of the file to generate. -->
    <PropertyGroup>
      <InfoVersionFilename Condition="'$(InfoVersionFilename)' == ''">InfoVersion.cs</InfoVersionFilename>
      <InfoVersionFile Condition="'$(InfoVersionFile)' == ''">$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(InfoVersionFilename)</InfoVersionFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Delete the file if it exists from a priopr build. -->
    <Delete Files="$(InfoVersionFile)" Condition="Exists('$(InfoVersionFile)')" />

    <!-- Generate the source file. -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <InfoVersionAttribute Include="AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute"  Condition="'$(InformationalVersion)' != ''">
        <value>$(InformationalVersion)</value>
      </InfoVersionAttribute>
    </ItemGroup>
    <WriteCodeFragment Language="C#" AssemblyAttributes="@(InfoVersionAttribute)" OutputFile="$(InfoVersionFile)"  Condition="'@(InfoVersionAttribute)' != ''">
      <Output TaskParameter="OutputFile" PropertyName="$(InfoVersionSourceFile)" />
    </WriteCodeFragment>

    <!-- Add the generated source file to the items to compile. -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="$(InfoVersionSourceFile)" Condition="Exists('$(InfoVersionSourceFile)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

In a CI build, a property value can be passed on the command line with the `-property` switch. `-p` is the short form.

e.g.

```
msbuild ... -p:InformationalVersion=foobar
```

or

```
dotnet build ... -p:InformationalVersion=foobar
```

As a design issue I would avoid coupling the build to a specific version control tool, i.e. I would not call `git` from within the build code.

Comment: I would really appreciate the sample code you mentioned. I think I have something close to working. I still have problems writing the file. For some reason <WriteLinesToFile File="Properties\VersionAttribute.cs" Overwrite="true" Encoding="utf-8" Lines="using System.Reflection&#x3B;&#xD;&#xA;[assembly: AssemblyVersion(&quot;$(VersionAttribute)&quot;)]" /> is not adding the ';' after the using statement.

Comment: FYI: I did try WriteCodeFragment It generates a file. I'm not sure how to insert the string from Git Describe into it.

Comment: Setup 2 and 3 are working. I don't know what you mean by " Pass the value into the build process."